# PHP & CSS - nav bar not highlighting the current tab

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to display a webpage with the following tabbed style navbar when clicked : 
[image: EXample webpage with selected tab style]

But I getting this result, even if I click on the links several times :
[image: This coming up]

(kindly ignore texts, those are examples from a reference book)
Below is my code :

```
<?php
// complete code for index.php
// reporting error if any
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// main code
include_once "classes/page_data.class.php";
$pageData = new stdClass(); // (old) declaring a new anonymous class object
$pageData->title = "My Portfolio";  // setting title name;
$pageData->content = include_once "views/navigation.php"; // setting content to page_data() class object
$pageData->css = "<link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet' />"; // CSS stylesheet added from css folder
//changes end here

// URL variable starts here
$navigationIsSet = $_GET['page'];   // Click to get page URL via variable 'page' in $_GET['page url'] superglobal array
if ($navigationIsSet)   // checking if a page has been clicked
    $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];    //get the clicked page's URL value
else
    $fileToLoad = 'skills';     // default page view
$pageData->content .= include_once "views/$fileToLoad.php"; // concatenate URL in the content
//URL variable ends here

//new code below: dynamic style added below
$pageData->embeddedCSS = "
<style>
nav a[href *= \'?page=$fileToLoad\']:visited{
padding:3px;
background-color:white;
border-top-left-radius:3px;
border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
</style>";

$page = include_once "templates/page.php"; // linking pages
echo $page;
?>
```

and this is from `layout.css` file :

```
body{
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
nav {
    background-color: #CCCCDE;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Also if you want to check `page.php` :

```
<?php
return  "<!DOCTYPE html> 
         <html>
         <head>
         <title>$pageData->title</title> 
         <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='test/html; charset=utf-8'/>
         </head>
         <body>
         $pageData->content
         $pageData->css
         </body>
         </html>";
         ?>
```

Now that reference book has almost same code to generate the snapshot 1, while my code doesn't show the tabbed nav bar while the user clicks on the links.
Can you please help me to find out what's wrong with the `index.php` dynamic style ? I'm using PHPStorm with PHP 7.2 as php IDE.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When clicked on a tab, a css class should be added to that navbar item. So you can change the css like `background-color` for that single item

Comment: @Svenmarim thanks for the reply. But where should I change? in `index.php` or inside `layout.css` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `active` class to the current selected tab. In that css class you can change the style for only that tab. Below here you see how to add the `active` class with an `if` statement to a `li` object in your navbar. Then in your style.css you can change i.e. the background-color for that class.

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $this->uri->segment(1) ?>/home" 
             class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="home"){echo 'active';}?>">
             Home
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I just added this line `echo "$pageData->embeddedCSS";`
 before `$page = include_once "templates/page.php"; // linking pages` in `index.php` . It works great !

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer accidentally ;)

before `$page = include_once "templates/page.php"; // linking pages`

add this `echo "$pageData->embeddedCSS";`

this works exactly as I wanted. :D